# Lodash : Extent by adding to attribute

Tags: lodash

```
[
  {
    "Office_Id": 100,
    "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 200,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  },
  {
    "Office_Id": 300,
     "Address1": "xxxxx",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "ANNISTON",
    "District_Id": 1277,
    "OfficeName": "test"
  }
]
```

Using lodash how can i add a new attribute by combining Office_Id And OfficeName

```
{
        "Office_Id": 300,
         "Address1": "xxxxx",
        "Address2": "",
        "City": "ANNISTON",
        "District_Id": 1277,
        "OfficeName": "offce_ttttt",
         "office": "300 - offce_ttttt"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mutating the original objects:

```
offices = _.forEach(offices, function (o) {
  _.assign(o, { office: o.Office_Id + ' - ' + o.OfficeName })
})
```

Without mutating the original objects:

```
var newObjects = _.map(offices, function (o) {
  return _.assign({}, o, { office: o.Office_Id + ' - ' + o.OfficeName })
})
```